# Controlling 2-pole contactor using Arduino

Tags: power-supply, transistors, mosfet, relay, contactor

I am working with [Packard C230C contactor](https://openev.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/attachments/6066213440) to develop own EVSE. For a simple start i just want to toggle contactor using Arduino. OpenEVSE is already doing it. Just want to know how do they do it and some circuit explanation.

Reference : OpenEVSE Setup
 [image]

Comment: Where is the "circuit diagram" ?

Comment: I dont have any. I am on this project where a 230v 40Amp C230C contactor is controlled by Arduino. Project is related to E-Vehicle charging. This is what the contactor looks like - https://www.ebay.com/itm/Packard-C230C-Definite-Purpose-Contactor-2-Pole-/161584186692

Comment: You have a contactor with a 240VAC coil (probably a number of watts and rather inductive). It is very unlikely it will work on 12VDC (might work on 48VDC or it might burn up or it might not pull in smartly enough). Pick a more appropriate contactor to start with.